# adding value of input box to URL as a param after a button is pressed?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rhtml

I have one input field and 2 buttons, each button performs a different function. i want one of the buttons to take the value of the input field and add it to a specified Url (as a param) that button should go to.

so if the value inserted in to the box is "dog" then after clicking the button the URL should be `"/go_somwhere?value=dog"`

can i do it in just html or do i need a ruby method?

i'm using rails.

thanks

Comment: the other button calls a ruby method that makes a search, that's already in place. im trying to add the new button that will take the value of the input box and add it as a param and go to a new entirely different page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you would need to do this via javascript on the client side  . The button should have a function attached to its click event . This function should read the value from the input box and change the url ( window.locations ) .

Answer (score 2):

```
<% form_for :item, :url=>{:action=>'go_somwhere'}, :html => { :method=>"get"} do|f| %>

<%= text_field_tag :value, "" %>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >

<% end %>
```

Comment: It will work if its in a form tag. You can access that value from controller's action as `param[:value]`. Your other button that you mentioned should be outside the `form_for` block